# How to properly use Yup schema with single react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, formik, yup

I'm using `react-select` with `Formik` and `Yup` to validate my form, but for some reason my validation is not working. My Schema looks like this:

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
age: Yup.object().shape({
    label: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    value: Yup.string().required("Required")
})
});
```

And my data looks like this:

```
export const ageOptions = [
  { value: 0.1, label: "Not born yet" },
  { value: 0.3, label: "Baby - 0 to 3 months" },
  { value: 0.6, label: "Baby - 3 to 6 months" },
  { value: 0.12, label: "Baby - 6 to 12 months" },
  { value: 0.18, label: "Baby - 12 to 18 months" },
  { value: 0.24, label: "Baby - 18 to 24 months" },
  { value: 2, label: "2 years" },
  { value: 3, label: "3 years" },
  { value: 4, label: "4 years" },
  { value: 5, label: "5 years" },
  { value: 6, label: "6 years" },
  { value: 7, label: "7 years" },
  { value: 8, label: "8 years" },
  { value: 9, label: "9 years" },
  { value: 10, label: "10 years" },
  { value: 11, label: "11 years" },
  { value: 12, label: "12 years" },
  { value: 13, label: "13 years" },
  { value: 14, label: "14 years" }
];
```

When I select an option in the select inside the UI, the following error is returned:

```
age must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `0.6`). If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`
```

How do I make the validation work correctly?

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w210nqzpww)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You require `age` to be of type `object`, but set it the value of the selected option. That is what triggers your wrong validation. Here is how to fix your validation:

1. If you want to keep `age` to be an object, change your schema to the following:

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
    age: Yup.object().shape({
        label: Yup.string().required("Required"),
        value: Yup.string().required("Required")
    })
});
```

else set it to the following:

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
    age: Yup.string()
});
```

2. Update your `onChange` on the `Select` component to set the value to the `option` instead of the `option.value` if you want to use the object in your schema validation.

```
<Select
    { ... }
    value={field.value} // This can be set like this as a result of the change
    onChange={option => form.setFieldValue(field.name, option)}
/>
```

That should get it to work.

Comment: Hey @Rallen, thanks for the response. I've done what you said and updated the Codesandbox (which gets rid of the previous error) but the validation still doesn't work, e.g if you click submit when no selection has been made, it won't display an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `.nullable()` to your `age` shape and `age: null` to `initialValues`.

Comment: Hi @Rallen, thanks again for your response. I've done what you said and it still doesn't work. Have you tested it yourself in a Sandbox?

Comment: The validation in your sandbox works as expected. What exactly is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Hey @Rallen, on line 43 there's an `<ErrorMessage name="age" />` component which should display the string 'Required' if you click submit without having selected an option from the dropdown. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you want `Required` to be the error you should add `.required("Required")` behind `.nullable()` of the `age` shape. This was not clear based on your question.

Comment: Thanks @Rallen, that works. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks @Rallen, that also worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yup Validation Schema

```
const validationSchema = function (values) {
  return Yup.object().shape({  
    courseId: Yup.string().required("Required").nullable()
  })
}
```

React-select custom class component

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

class SingleSelectField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleChange = (item) => {
    if (item) this.props.onChange(this.props.type, item.value);
    else this.props.onChange(this.props.type, "");
  };

  handleBlur = () => {
    this.props.onBlur(this.props.type, true);
  };

  render() {
    const defaultValue = (options, value) => {
      return options ? options.find((option) => option.value === value) : "";
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={this.props.options}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          value={defaultValue(this.props.options, this.props.value)}
          isClearable
        />
        {!!this.props.error && this.props.touched && (
          <div style={{ color: "red", marginTop: ".5rem" }}>{this.props.error}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { SingleSelectField as default };
```

Comment: Hi, why you use "!!"? its doble negation? what is the purpose?, thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla , double negation operator ( !! ) can be used to convert a value to a boolean